# coneigniter: linking controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to link a controller to another page.
I have an index page that contains the login and now I need to link the controller and the login link:

```
    <div class="toplogin">
        <p><a href="login">SIGN IN</a> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#">REGISTER</a></p>
    </div>    

    <div class="header_phone">
        <p>CALL US NOW: &nbsp; <strong>1-800-531-453</strong></p>
    </div>          

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: here i want to link login controller at <a href="login">SIGN IN</a>

Comment: `coneignite`? Is that like CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link `<a href="controller_name/login">SIGN IN</a>` where "controller_name" is the name of your controller file and "login" is the name of the method.

In your controller_name.php file:

```
public function login(){

    //do login stuff

    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in codeignitor, we link by calling the controller function eg, if you have a controller register in which you have this function getdata(), then we link it by calling <`a href="register/getdata">REGISTER</a>`